# Switch Twig condition Case with OR condition (two values in the case)

Tags: templating, switch

I got a Twig `switch` in a template like:

```
{% switch bodyClass %}

    {% case 'A' %}
        ...

    {% case 'B' %}
        ...

    {% default %}
        ...

{% endswitch %}
```

I would like to add another possible value for the first `case`.
So I would have `case 'A' or 'C'`.

Is it possible in Twig syntax?

=================================
**EDIT CRAFT BUG ?**
OK lets try to rephrase, sorry for my english not easy to explain for me sometimes :)
So when the `or` syntax is added, then the 2nd and 3rd cases `B` or `default` (after `'A1' or 'A2'` case) are never reached anymore.
The switch always say `TRUE` to 1st case (even if it is wrong...).

```
{% switch bodyClass %}

    {% case 'A1' or 'A2' %}
        ...

    {% case 'B' %}
        ...

    {% default %}
        ...

{% endswitch %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This currently isn't a supported syntax for the Twig switch statement.

Craft will take that line and compile it down to:

```
case ("A1" || "A2"):
```

Which will always evaluate to `true`, which is why you always get the first result.

In order for it to work, it would need to be either:

```
case "A1":
case "A2":
```

To take advantage of PHP's fall-through support or the more ugly:

```
case ($context["bodyClass"] == "A1" || $context["bodyClass"] == "A2")
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it just before your answer by intuition and it worked ! Cool :D

Comment: Hey Brad I think I got a Craft bug here : now my template only show first case (A or C), even when it is false.

Comment: It worked yesterday, but today it doesn't?

Comment: Because I just checked `case A or C` yesterday. I did not check the other cases. Thats why I did not see it... I really double checked the value of `bodyclass` before the switch. And it displays B. But the switch return `A or C` case.

Comment: Not sure I'm following... what's the value of `bodyClass` that causes B to be displayed?

Comment: Sorry Brad my english is tired :) I tried to rephrase above in my main question, below EDIT CRAFT BUG?

Comment: Ahh, that does look like a bug, then.  Will look into it.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to completely change my answer on this. :)

Comment: @BradBell: I don't think the Craft switch tag supports the php fall through. Pretty sure you get a `break;` for free with every `case`.

Comment: Sorry brad I come back here, you mean I must avoir using switch here ? This syntax `"A1": case "A2":`  is Craft switch case syntax ? no ?

Comment: @migswd Yeah, Craft's Twig switch statement won't work for this.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` tag is a Twig extension that comes as part of Craft. From looking at the code for the `Switch_TokenParser` in the Craft [full class reference](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/Switch_TokenParser) it looks as if it is expecting an expression after `case` so you should be able to put in any valid Twig expression that equates to `true` or `false`.